# Configuring an Entityform with a term reference field

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have an entityform that users use to upload pdf files. On the form there is a 'Term Reference' field (select list) that lets them choose the type of document that they are uploading, e.g. 'letter', 'contract', 'invoice' etc...

These entityform submissions are then displayed as a view with the 'term reference' field displayed next to a link to the uploaded document.

My problem is that when I click on the term reference the term's page is not populated with the entityform submissions that have been labeled with it.

Comment: Is you term page coming from the view "Taxonomy term"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add new view that shows content of type: entityform submissions.
- Add a field Entityform Submission field 'Document type'
- Set the path to /taxonomy/term/%
- Add a contextual filter, entityform submission 'Document type' and 'provide default value' - 'taxonomy term ID from url'

Done.